# Cross foreign key Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I need to create two tables such as:

- `Id_faculty_reference` and `Id_professor` are primary keys (that works)
- `Id_dean` is a foreign key with reference to `Id_professor`
- `Id_faculty` is a foreign key with reference to `Id_faculty_reference` (the problem).

I tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty(
      Id_faculty_reference int PRIMARY KEY,
      faculty_name varchar,
      Id_dean int
);

CREATE TABLE Professors(
      Id_professor int PRIMARY KEY,
      Name varchar,
      Last_name varchar,
      Salary int,
      Id_faculty int REFERENCES Faculty(id_faculty_reference)
);

ALTER TABLE Faculty ADD FOREIGN KEY (Id_dean)
   REFERENCES Professors(id_professor);
```

The problem comes when I try to add information into the tables. If I try to add info into `Faculty`, there is no reference, because `Professors` is empty:

```
Key is not present in table "Professors"
```

If I try to add info into `Professors`, there is no reference because Faculty is empty:

```
Key is not present in table "Faculty"
```

The mistake makes sense to me, but my professor says that what he asks can be done; how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

There are three approaches:

1. First insert a `faculty` where `id_dean` is NULL. Then insert a `professors` that references that `faculty` entry. Then update the first entry to point to the second.

   This works because `id_dean` can be NULL, and a foreign key that is set to NULL is not enforced.

   In general it is a good idea to have as many columns `NOT NULL` as possible. In that case use one of the other methods.
2. Foreign keys are checked at the end of the statement, so insert both rows in a single statement:

   ```
   WITH newfac AS (
      INSERT INTO faculty (...) VALUES (...)
      RETURNING id
   )
   INSERT INTO professors (id_faculty, ...)
   SELECT newfac.id, ...
   FROM newfac;
   ```
3. Use a deferred foreign key constraint:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE faculty(
      ...,
      id_dean int REFERENCES professors DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
   );
   ```

   Such a foreign key constraint is not checked at the end of the statement, but at the end of the transaction. So you can first enter the `faculty`, then the `professors`, as long as you do it in a single database transaction.